# How to modify a Debian (Buster) installer to include a preseed.cfg?

Tags: debian-installer, preseed

I took the Debian ISO and created a bootable USB stick with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/). After that I modified the stick to include my `preseed.cfg`:

```
#! /bin/bash

initrd="/mnt/install.amd/initrd.gz"

rm -rf tmp
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
gzip -d < "$initrd" | cpio -i

cp ../preseed.cfg .

mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt

find | cpio -o --format=newc | gzip -9c > "$initrd"

umount /mnt
```

When I start the installation,
the installer does not ask for the language any more. 
I would say the installer has read the `preseed.cfg` file and used the configured language.

But the installer refuses to mount the installation source and throws an error. But the installer does not explain what is wrong. Maybe some kind of checksum mismatches because of the modification.

I do not know what else I need to update. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this link in the documentation of Debian Installer:

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed/EditIso